# Hide a form on Form Load event?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, forms, form-load

I need to add a commandline option to hide mi application if the parameter to hide the form is passed...

It's a Windowsform.

This is what I've tried but the form don't hides:

```
Private Sub Parse_Arguments()
    For I As Integer = 0 To My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Count - 1

        If My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Item(I).ToLower = "/s" Then
            Me.Visible = False
            Me.Hide()
            'Me.Visible = True
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @Freelancer no matter the language, I can translate it later, but i preffer VB.NET,  thanks for comment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901848/how-do-i-handle-command-line-arguments-in-winforms-if-i-dont-want-to-load-main refer, might be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this technique : it wont hide it, but it will be minimized:

```
Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
```

if you don't want it showing on the task bar either, you can add this line:

```
Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Set Opacity() to 0 (zero), and FormBorderStyle() to SizableToolWindow:

```
Private Sub Parse_Arguments()
    For I As Integer = 0 To My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Count - 1
        If My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Item(I).ToLower = "/s" Then
            Me.Opacity = 0 ' completely invisible
            Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow ' hide from alt-tab
            Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```